# Domain name not routing with Heroku and Namecheap

Tags: heroku, dns, web-hosting, namecheap

I recently purchased a domain name with namecheap.com, and added a CNAME record from my Heroku app where I am running the application. I am sure that I added the correct domain name to my Heroku app, and the correct DNS target to my CNAME on Namecheap web settings.

Previously it was working, but this morning I purchased an SSL certificate on Namecheap, and my domain just points to a Namecheap page saying "This domain is registered with Namecheap".

I followed all the steps to properly activate the SSL certificate, and it even says it's activated on Namecheap on the domain I want. Also what's strange is the the Heroku domains appear to have good ACM status.

So on the surface everything seems to be all right, but when you go to my domain my app doesn't show up.

Any idea as to why this is? Also if you have any more information you want to know feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to delete the default records on the domain. Initially namecheap sets a reroute, and CNAME for their parking lot page.

These need to be removed so that they don't interfere with the domain routing that you want.